# How to fail a build when an ant file calls a batch file which calls an ant file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, ant, junit

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have an ant file which calls a .batch file which calls an ant file to build a component.

If the component building fails, I want the main ant file to fail the build.

**Main ant file**

```
<target name="TestingThree">
  <exec executable="${basedir}\..\..\Component\UnitTests.bat" dir="${basedir}\..\..\Component">
    <arg line='run'/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

**Batch file**

```
if "%1" == "run" call ant -buildfile build.xml test
```

**Building component ant file**

```
<target name="test" depends="compile.test, -injectSigningKeys" description="Run Component tests">

    <junit haltonfailure="yes" printsummary="yes" showoutput="yes">
    <test name="Component.TestSuite" todir="${report}" filtertrace="on" />
    <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
    <classpath refid="test.classpath" />

    </junit>
</target>
```

Currently whenever I execute the main ant file, the .batch file will be called, and the other ant file will be called which fails the build. But the main ant build still succeeds.

Is there a way for the .batch file to return fail/succeed to the main ant file?
I cannot directly call the second ant file from the main ant file. Neither can I transfer the code from the second ant file to the main ant file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you took a look at the `failonerror` parameter ?

> By default the return code of a  is ignored; when you set
>   failonerror="true" then any return code signaling failure (OS
>   specific) causes the build to fail. [Exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)